# Code First Migration for Firebird 2.5

Tags: ef-code-first, firebird2.5

I have startup project on **ASP.NET MVC 5**. I want to use **Code First** with **Firebird 2.5**.

After enabled migrations and after added first migration, I try update database:

```
add-migration test
update-database
```

But I get error:

> The name '**FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId**' is longer than
>   Firebird's 31 characters limit for object names.

How can I change the name `FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId` to shorter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First and Firebird - Foreign Key name issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789394/entity-framework-code-first-and-firebird-foreign-key-name-issue)